# MockedProvider does not work when Component query changes

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have simplified problem into these files

TestComp.tsx

```
    export const TestComp: FC<> = () => {
  const [testValue, setTestValue] = React.useState(5);

  const where = React.useMemo(() => testValue, [testValue]);

  const { data: productsData } = useQuery<QueryProductsResult>(QUERY_PRODUCTS, {
    variables: {
      where,
    },
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    setTestValue(7);
  }, 0);

  console.log(productsData, where);

  return <div>content</div>;
};
```

TestComp.test.tsx

```
const productsData = [
  {
    ... some data ...
  },
];

const mockContractPricing = [
  {
    request: {
      query: QUERY_PRODUCTS,
      variables: {
        where: 7,
      },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        products: productsData,
      },
    },
  },
];

describe('dsfgdas', () => {
  it('ggg', async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mockContractPricing} addTypename={false}>
        <TestComp />
      </MockedProvider>
    );

    await act(() => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)));

    console.log(container.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

So when where is updated it does not work. If I put where=7 since in the beginning it does not work. But if it is changing inside the component it never works out. Even trying to make it where: 7 in the mocked query it doesn't work.

The setTimeout is put only for demonstration purpose.

Is there any way to do it?

Console output:

console.log
undefined 5

console.log
undefined 7

console.log
content

Comment: You really need to explain what "it does not work" means, whatever evidence you have of that, and what you expected.

Comment: I have shown the console output. And as you can see it is undefined. productsData is undefined always.